# Are the positions required for UEFI / GPT secure?

Tags: windows, uefi, gpt

I recently manually set up UEFI for my windows install. Today I read an article about Lenovo shipping malware on the UEFI positions of some of their laptops.

This got me wondering, is the partition actually secure, or could a user mode application somehow write to it in order to achieve permission escalation and overwrite system files during boot?

Comment: Positions or partitions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to [this report.](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/08/12/lenovo-used-a-hidden-windows-feature-to-ensure-its-software-could-not-be-deleted/) Briefly, Lenovo has been using its firmware to ensure that a particular Windows binary (`C:\Windows\system32\autochk.exe`) is the Lenovo version, not the Microsoft version. If it's Microsoft's version, it's replaced by Lenovo's version. The binary then downloads two more Lenovo binaries that report back on how you're using the computer. [Lenovo's security advisory](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/product_security/lse_bios_notebook) refers ambiguously to "vulnerabilities" in this system, but I don't know offhand precisely what this means -- presumably it's something potentially worse than Lenovo's keeping certain files installed on your computer without bothering to ask you about that.

Note that these flaws don't really have much to do with the "security" of "partitions," except of course insofar as `C:` resides on a partition on the disk. It's really the *firmware itself* into which Lenovo has inserted its bloatware.

As I understand it, there are three key issues here:

- Lenovo has issued both a program that disables this bloatware feature and updated firmware that omits the feature entirely.
- Unless this is the proverbial "tip of the iceberg," not all Lenovo products are affected.
- I doubt if this would affect you if you were to wipe Windows and use nothing but another OS (Linux, FreeBSD, etc.).

See [Lenovo's own service advisory](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/product_security/lse_bios_notebook) for more definitive information on this subject, including a list of affected models and links to the disabler utility and firmware ("BIOS," although that's a misnomer) updates.

Comment: Yeah that's the one. However,I'm not affected by this Lenovo thing. I'm merely wondering whether rogue software can write something to those partitions in order to achieve a similar effect. This is kind of like a rootkit right?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the "vulnerability" to which Lenovo referred would enable just that -- unauthorized software using this feature to keep itself installed. I wouldn't call the feature *itself* a "rootkit," but that's basically a question of semantics; by whatever name, Lenovo's firmware feature is ill-conceived, at best.

Comment: Right. Really, it seems like Lenovo is just leveraging functionality provided by newer motherboards with questionable intent. I'm not focused on Lenovo specifically, but trying to understand whether having these partitions makes you vulnerable to a new class of attacks. The partitions are not specific to Lenovo or windows specifically, but rather to implementations of UEFI / GPT.

Comment: It's not the motherboards precisely that are the issue; it's the firmware (which is stored on the motherboard). Lenovo isn't *leveraging* functionality in the firmware; it *created* the functionality, since it created the firmware -- or, more precisely, contracted for it to be created. Also, once again, *partitions* aren't the issue at all. It's not clear to me what you mean by that comment, but you're either mis-using the term "partition" or are very confused about what the issue is. To the best of my knowledge based on the public information, this issue *is* Lenovo-specific.